# Rails Problems, Missing Template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, templates

I'm a newbie to Rails and beginning my crud application. I've created the form perfectly fine but when I click the submit button this error appears, could someone please explain the error and how I would go about resolving this error

```
Missing template posts/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/Users/shannon/beginner/app/views"
```

My controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
 def new
end

def create
 render plain: params[:posts].inspect
end
```

Comment: Please add code of your controller - it will help to address your problem accordingly

Comment: The code you've posted could not produce the error you describe. Rails will not attempt to render `posts/create` if your `create` action already renders something. Is it possible this is the wrong controller?

Comment: @meagar, she is using wrong rendering option, render `plain` is added in Rails 4.1, and she is using may be 4.0, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

May be you are using Rails version prior 4.1, `render` `plain` is added in `Rails 4.1`. So Rails is ignoring `plain` option and looking for template `posts/create`.

in **Rails 4.1** you can do:

```
render plain: params[:posts].inspect
```

in **Rails 4.0** you need to do:

```
render text: params[:posts].inspect
```